# Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running this query against an Oracle database using SQL Developer. It is giving me an error message about an invalid identifier "%s". What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH security_menu_Recursive(Parent,MenuId,obj,LEVEL)
    AS
    (
        SELECT MZMNI,MZMTOE,MZOBNM,0 AS LEVEL FROM 
        
    PRODDTA.PBS.PRODCTL.F00821
    WHERE MZMNI = 'G5509L2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MZMNI,MZMTOE,MZOBNM,Level + 1 AS LEVEL
         FROM PRODDTA.PBS.PRODCTL.F00821
        INNER JOIN security_menu_Recursive AS smr ON smr.mENUID = 
     MZMNI
    )
    SELECT parent,menuid,OBJ,LEVEL FROM security_menu_Recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEVEL` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621), and has a special meaning in the [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332) syntax. Even when using a hierarchical query you has to alias that pseudocolumn to another name if you want to refer to it in an outer query.

You need to change the name of that alias to something else.